# Element type is invalid: react router wordpress

Tags: reactjs, wordpress

I am trying to make react rendering work with router. Without router it was rendering fine in wordpress.  But now when I changed my index.js to include router , I keep getting
`react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10 Error: Minified React error #130;  Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.`.

```
import HomePageFlightContainer from './HomePageFlightContainer';
import PageFetch from './PageFetch';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Router >
            
                <Switch>
                   <Route path="/wordpress/search" component={PageFetch} />
                   <Route  path="/" component={HomePageFlightContainer} />
                </Switch>
            
        </Router>
    );
};


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Now, I also created a index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React App Setup</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root">

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

My `webpack.config` is

```
const defaults = require('@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config');

module.exports = {
  ...defaults,
  externals: {
    "react": 'React',
    "react-dom": 'ReactDOM',
  },
};
```

Why do I get element undefined when I have that in index.html .

**EDIT**

After learning that index.php is the entry point for react in wordpress from [here](https://www.jclabs.co.uk/create-a-react-wordpress-theme-using-babel-and-webpack/) , I added this in index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php language_attributes(); ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./dist/js/bundle.js"></script>. 
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

tried with `/js/bundle.js` in script above

and updated my webpack.config.js to

```
const path = require('path');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const webpackConfig = {
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        bundle: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js')
    },
    output: {
        filename: 'js/[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.(js|jsx)$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader'
                }
            },
            {
                test: /.(css|scss)$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: 'wp-content/themes/travel/dist/img/[name].[ext]'
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new BrowserSyncPlugin({
            proxy: {
                target: 'https://localhost'
            },
            files: ['**/*.php'],
            cors: true,
            reloadDelay: 0,
            open: false
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/style.[name].css',
        })
    ]
};

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    webpackConfig.mode = 'production';
}

module.exports = webpackConfig;
```

Now I get error `Target container is not a DOM element.` for `<div id="root"></div>` element afaik .

Anyone has any idea how to mount react `App` for wordpress

Answer (score 0):

After changing my index.php file , I was able to mount `App` on the root element as explained [here](https://www.jclabs.co.uk/create-a-react-wordpress-theme-using-babel-and-webpack/). The root element is in index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="<?php language_attributes(); ?>">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title><?php wp_title(); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="./dist/js/bundle.js"></script>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Also add this to functions.php . `bundle.js` is the output of webpack

```
   wp_enqueue_script('theme', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/dist/js/bundle.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true);
```